# Is there a keyboard shortcut for launching Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings, activity-monitor

I can't seem to find a shortcut for launching the activity monitor. Does it have one?

Comment: Why don't you just put it in Dock?

Comment: related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86010/ctrl-alt-delete-mac-equivalent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save in AppleScript Editor and assign a shortcut in [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) or [some other way](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-shell-script-in-os-x/264943#264943):

```
tell app "Activity Monitor"
    reopen -- makes a new window if there are no existing windows
    activate -- brings the app to front
end tell
```

Comment: Is there a way to change this script so that the Activity Monitor window opens up in a normal size (i.e. not maximized).

Answer (score 17):

Not by default, but you can <strike>create one in System Preferences --> Keyboard --> Keyboard Shortcuts.  Or you can</strike> use spotlight:

- type <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>
- start typing "activity monitor"
- as soon as activity monitor is highlighted in the spotlight list, hit <kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: Sadly, I don't believe System Prefs can set keyboard shortcuts to launch apps.

Comment: @Dori: wow, you're right.  That's what I get for assuming... I've seen the application shortcuts section in keyboard shortcuts and assumed it would allow me to create one for launching an application.  I just never tried it since I always use spotlight.  I struck through that text in my answer since it's incorrect.  Good catch.

Comment: The (global) AppleScript menu used to let you launch Apps via keyboard shortcut, but Apple took that capability out years ago.

Answer (score 9):

Create in Automator an Action to launch Activity Monitor:

[image]

Then in System Preferences -> Shortcuts Tab -> Services set a keyboard shortcut for the created service:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, Activity Monitor is grayed out when trying to select it in Automator's Launch Application. Is there something I missed from the 1st screenshot? This is on Monterey (12.6) on an M1 MBA.

Answer (score 5):

Otherwise of Spotloight that @Calavera suggest you can use 3rd-party software such as:

1. **[QuickSilver](http://www.blacktree.com/?quicksilver)**
2. **[Namely](http://amarsagoo.info/namely/)**
3. **[TigerLaunch](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/9152/tigerlaunch)**
4. **[HimmelBar](http://softbend.free.fr/himmelbar/)**
5. **[LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html)**

I myself use QuickSilver and set shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to run it and type some part of "Activity Monitor" and press <kbd>⌫</kbd> so Activity Monitor will run.

[image]

Comment: Add to that list [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html), personally I prefer typing just `ac` to launch the Activity Monitor.

Comment: Tho' I prefer LaunchBar over QuickSilver, both can launch Activity Monitor by simply typing ‘ac’, it’s a matter of training. :)

Comment: I think Alfred is the best.

Comment: You may want to add [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php).

Answer (score 3):

For starting apps, scripts, etc. with a single shortcut, there exist some specific tools.

1. NuKit - free trial, download from MacUpdate or their site.
2. Apptivate - 2.0 is no longer free and as of now, it's unfortunately traded usability for eye candy.

Apptivate offers to switch away from apps with the same shortcut. The NuKit team promised to add it soon.

Answer (score 3):

You can use System keyboard shortcuts, Services and Automator to do this.
See my answer to a similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38003/17128)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way is using aliases. Most pro users use them pretty frequently and I have one for launching Activity Monitor as well.

---

<strike>Even on macOS Big Sur my default shell is bash and not zsh. Put the following line in `~/.bash_profile` file:</strike> (I switched to `zsh` finally. All of my `bash` aliases worked fine except for the ones containing special characters. I just added a `\` in front of the special characters to escape them and then it all worked as expected.)

Put the following line in `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias am="open -a activity\ monitor"
```

Now, all you have to do is type `am` in Terminal, press enter, and it opens Activity Monitor.

---

FWIW, here's other aliases too that I have in my `~/.zshrc` that have incredibly improved my ability to use macOS:

```sh
#####  ----------  File Access Commands....  ----------

alias ll="ls -lahG"
alias co="curl -O"
alias editsh="nano ~/.zshrc;source ~/.zshrc"
alias mv="mv -iv"
alias cp="cp -iv"
alias cll="clear;ll"
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ..\..'
```

```sh
#####  ---------  Git Commands  --------
alias gtalias="alias | grep \"^alias gt\""
alias gts="git status"
alias gtd="git diff"
alias gtpull="git pull"
alias gtlog="git log"
alias gtc="git checkout"
alias gtcmas="gtc master"
alias gtb="git branch"
alias gtpush="git push"
alias gtst="git stash"
alias gtstpop="gtst pop"
alias gtstapply="gtst apply"
alias gtstsv="gtst save"
alias gtstli="gtst list"
alias gtctall="git commit -a"
alias gtmm="git merge origin/master"
alias gtsu="git submodule update"
```

```sh
#### Application & Web Access Commands - 1

alias int="open -a IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE"
alias slk="open -a slack"
alias am="open -a activity\ monitor"
alias rdc="open -na Microsoft\ Remote\ Desktop"
alias smc="open -a Cisco\ AnyConnect\ Secure\ Mobility\ Client"
alias rdt="s https://www.reddit.com/"
alias frdt="ff https://www.reddit.com/"
alias mu="osascript -e \"set volume output volume 0\""
alias fv="osascript -e \"set volume output volume 100\""

alias tv="open -a tv"
alias cln="open -a clion"
alias mail="open -a mail"
alias keys="open -a KeyChain\ Access"
alias ss="open -a screen\ sharing"
alias dul="open -a disk\ utility"
alias maps="s https://maps.google.com"
alias map="open -a maps"

alias msg="open -a messages"
alias ft="open -a facetime"
alias pref="open -a System\ Preferences"
alias tpb="ffp https://thepiratebay.org/"
```

```sh
#### Application & Web Access Commands - 2
alias ntw="open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Network.prefPane/"
alias dsp="open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Displays.prefPane/"
alias pdf="open -a preview"
alias ppt="open -a Microsoft\ PowerPoint"
alias pages="open -a pages"
alias knote="open -a keynote"

alias news="open -a news"
alias P="open -a photos"

alias c="open -a google\ chrome"
alias cprv="c --args --incognito"
alias intn="open -na IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE"
alias v="open -a vlc"
alias nv="open -na vlc"
alias s="open -a safari"
alias ns="open -na safari"
alias m="open -a music"

stck="https://stackoverflow.com/"
alias sto="s $stck"
alias csto="c $stck"
alias fsto="ff $stck"

alias yut="s https://www.youtube.com/feed/history"

alias dict="open -a dictionary"
alias wiki="s https://en.wikipedia.org"
```

```sh
##### Machine Admin Commands

alias apon="sudo networksetup -setairportpower en1 on"
alias apoff="sudo networksetup -setairportpower en1 off"
alias apc="apoff;apon"
alias apc-="apon;apoff"
alias rshut="sudo shutdown -r now"
alias hshut="pmset -g batt;sudo osascript -e \"set Volume 0\";brt 0.01;sudo shutdown -h now"
alias sshut="sudo shutdown -s now"
```

---

Side Note: To learn how to migrate your aliases from bash to zsh, see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/371867/71941).

Answer (score 1):

You can you use [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net) to create keyboard shortcuts and even use the trackpad to create a gesture instead of keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Also custom touch bar shortcuts as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org) is my favorite and is probably the most easiest to install and configure. 
Here is the init.lua code for launching the Activity Monitor.

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd","shift"}, "Escape", function()
   hs.application.open("Activity Monitor")
end)
```

PS: I mapped my command key to control. So by mapping the hotkey to "cmd+shift+escape", I get similar functionality that I get in Windows(for opening the task manager)