# Can I create a keyboard shortcut to open a specific application on OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I want to create a keyboard shortcut to i.e. open Firefox *while* I am working in another application. I know I can use <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> when I am in Firefox to open a new tab.

I haven't found a way to create that kind of shortcuts in System Preferences.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### Karabiner-Elements (10.12 and later)

Karabiner stopped working in 10.12 due to changes in the kernel architecture, and Karabiner was rewritten as Karabiner-Elements which uses a new JSON format for the configuration files.

You can now add a rule like this to [`karabiner.json`](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html):

```json
{
  "from": {
    "key_code": "t",
    "modifiers": {
      "mandatory": ["right_option"]
    }
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "shell_command": "open -a terminal"
    }
  ],
  "type": "basic"
}
```

This makes a short press of the right command key open Emacs:

```json
{
  "from": {
    "key_code": "right_command",
    "modifiers": {
      "optional": ["any"]
    }
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "key_code": "right_command",
      "lazy": true
    }
  ],
  "to_if_alone": [
    {
      "shell_command": "open -a emacs"
    }
  ],
  "type": "basic"
}
```

### Karabiner (10.11 and earlier)

Save a file like this as [`private.xml`](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_Safari</name>
    <url>file:///Applications/Safari.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_iTunes</name>
    <url>file:///Applications/iTunes.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_EMACS</name>
    <url>file:///Applications/Emacs.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F11, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_Safari</autogen>

    <!-- change the right option key into an extra modifier key -->
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::VK_MODIFIER_EXTRA1</autogen>

    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::I, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_iTunes</autogen>

    <!-- make a short press of the right command open Emacs -->
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_EMACS</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

### Alfred 2

If you have bought the Powerpack for Alfred 2, you can create a workflow like this:

[image: Screenshot of a workflow in Alfred]

Hotkeys have a short delay by default, but you can reduce the delay by changing the "Trigger behaviour" option from "Simulate modifier keys released" to "Pass through modifier keys (Fastest)":

[image: Screenshot showing the change in 'Trigger behaviour']

### Automator services

Open Automator, select "Service" as the type of the document, change "Service receives" from "text" to "no input", add a "Launch Application" action, and save the service.

[image: Screenshot of Automator to create a workflow for launching an application]

Then assign a keyboard shortcut for the service from **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**.

[image: Screenshot of the Keyboard Prefs Pane with a shortcut to Open Terminal]

I don't recommend this option, because at least on my system, there is at best a delay of around half a second before an application is focused by a keyboard shortcut created using this method, and the delay is often even longer. There has also been a bug since 10.7 where the keyboard shortcuts for Automator services don't always work until you hover over the services menu from the menu bar. (Edit: it's now 8 years after I wrote this answer and the bug still hasn't been fixed.) Also, the keyboard shortcuts for services are not available in some applications like Emacs.

Comment: To open a new Terminal window every time you hit the shortcut, add applet: `osacompile -o "NewTerminalWindow.app" -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script' -e 'end'`(no spaces in the name). Then run once: `open -R "NewTerminalWindow.app"`. Now every time you run: `open -a NewTerminalWindow.app` - a new terminal window will be opened. E.g. you can use a last command in the Karabiner script. Link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/26033/436133

Answer (score 12):

I found [Apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com) the easiest to use. You just select an application and you assign a global shortcut. That's it.

Answer (score 8):

#### [Alfred](http://alfredapp.com)

Alfred, in its Power Pack version, can map shortcuts to applications, among many other features.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Get Quicksilver, http://www.blacktree.com/, it will allow you to set keyboard shortcuts to open apps. There are actually more many more apps that do this (Alfred, Keyboard Maestro etc etc.)

Mac OS X actually has a built-in way of doing that, but it doesn't work for Firefox, because it doesn't support services! http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090903085255430

Update Jan 2012: Blacktree no longer updates Quicksilver--the developer went to Google and has released [Google Quick Search Box](http://code.google.com/p/qsb-mac/). Quicksilver lives on, but it has a new home at [qsapp.com](http://qsapp.com/).

Comment: Quicksilver is great. Thanks so much for the advice. I created a bash script to open gmail and another to open mysms in the browser. Then I used the appify script to make them OS X apps. From there I could use Quicksilver to have my keyboard shortcuts to launch those. Very nice to have. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to use third party apps.
Then you can use Automator (Services ), and the Built in keyboard shortcuts.

Here is [how](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38003/17128) in an answer to a  similar question.

Very simple.

In Step **3**, of creating the service.

Set it to 'any application' .

i.e,
 *set Service receives to: 'no input' in 'any application' (Do this by using the drop downs at the top.)*

Answer (score 3):

As of macOS Monterey, you can set up a global hotkey via the Shortcuts app. This will either launch the app or switch to it if it's already running.

Use the Open App option and under settings, pick a shortcut from 'Run with'.

Works together nicely with a [hyper key](https://holmberg.io/hyper-key/).

[image: macOS Monterray shortcut to launch an app from a key binding]

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of good options here but I wanted to add my personal favorite which I've been using since 10.5 and still works on 10.11.2: **Spark 3**.

http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php

It's freeware and extremely easy to set up.  Here's the developer's description:

> Spark is a powerful, and easy Shortcuts manager. With Spark you can
>   create Hot Keys to launch applications and documents, execute
>   AppleScript, control iTunes, and more... You can also export and
>   import your Hot Keys library, or save it in HTML format to print it.
>   Spark is free, so use it without moderation!

Here's a screenshot of the interface:

[image: Spark User Interface]

Answer (score 2):

#### To open the Terminal with a keyboard shortcut without any third-party software:

- Open Automator (*⌘ + Space*, then type Automator)
- Go to *File -> New*
- Select **Quick Action** (or **Service**, depending on your Mac version)
- Where it says **Workflow receives**, select **no input**:

[image: how to open a mac terminal with keyboard shortcut]

- In the **Actions** column, search for **Run AppleScript** and drag it to the right column
- Paste this in the script area:

  ```
  on run {input, parameters}

      tell application "Terminal"
          do script ""
          activate
      end tell

  end run
  ```

*PS: Remove `do script ""` if you don't want a new instance of the terminal every time you press the hotkey.*

- Click on *File -> Save* and name it anything you want

[image: mac open terminal with keyboard shortcut]

- Now close Automator and open *System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts*
- In the left column, click on "Services"
- Scroll down to the very bottom, you should see the script you just saved. Click on **none** to assign a hotkey to it.

One important thing to consider, though, is that the hotkey must be unique across all applications. If you assign a common hotkey, such as *⌘ + T*, and try to open the terminal while browsing, it will conflict with most browser's hotkey to open a new tab, so it won't work. That's why you should try a shortcut that won't conflict with any app.

I've chosen **⌘ + ⌥ + F12**. Works pretty well.

#### Update

If you're using [iTerm2 + Oh My Zsh](https://laracasts.com/series/setup-a-mac-dev-machine-from-scratch/episodes/1), just replace **Run AppleScript** with **Launch Application** in Automator, and select **iTerm.app** from the list.

Comment: You don't need to use AppleScript: there is a Launch Application action.

Answer (score 1):

I know **Alfred** has already been mentioned, but I thought I'd say a little bit about choosing shortcut keys. It was not obvious to me at first what would be a good set of shortcuts that was (a) easy to remember, (b) easy to use, and (c) did not conflict with other system or application shortcut keys.

I ended up using the "alt" key as the basis, and generally relying on keys that can be triggered by the left hand, and choosing descriptive letters (e.g., x for Excel). this allows you to have the mouse in the right hand and the shortcut keys triggered with the left.

Another benefit of using Alfred Hotkeys to activate an application is that if an application is hidden, it will be unhidden.

Here's a screen shot of how I have it configured:
[image: example alfred hotkey configuration]

Answer (score 1):

## Thor

There is a nice clean open source app for this called Thor. It enabled you to assign global shortcuts to applications.

[image]

Download the binary from the App Store here https://itunes.apple.com/app/thor/id1120999687?ls=1&mt=12. The project page is here https://github.com/gbammc/Thor.

Answer (score 1):

If the Application is Terminal, this already has shortcut keys configured in Preferences:
[image: System Preferences Keyboard Shortcuts]
New Terminal at Folder <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

New Terminal at Tab Folder <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Tested on macOS Monterey

1. Open the `shortcuts` app
2. Click on `+` (new shortcut)
3. In the right sidebar search and double-click/drag `run AppleScript`
4. Paste script

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        reopen
    end tell
   end run
   ```

The best thing is you can assign the keyboard shortcut within the same app itself.

5. Navigate to `shortcut details` in the right sidebar.
6. You can find `Add keyboard shortcut`

Answer (score 0):

This version of AppleScript will **reuse** the existing Terminal, while open a new one if not exists.

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        if not (exists window 1) then reopen
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

The steps of using this script and assigning hotkey is well demonstrated by [Lucas Bustamante's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x/354630#354630)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for sharing, but your answer seems to be incomplete. Where does the keyboard shortcut come into play here (as asked in the question)?

Comment: Might also work as an edit to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354630/9058 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431395/9058.