# Set keyboard shortcuts for launching programs

Tags: macos, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I create a shortcut to open a specific application on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x)

On all my other machines, I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to launch a web browser, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> for an email client, etc.  I have looked but haven't been able to find how to set this up on my mac.  Can this be configured on a mac? Preferably without external software.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using an Automator service and assigning it a shortcut in the Keyboard System Preference pane:

1. Launch **Automator** and select “Service” as the type of new workflow to create.
2. Set the workflow to take “no input” in “all applications”.
3. Drag a “Run program“ action from the “Utilities” category into the workflow, set it to the app you want to start via a keyboard shortcut.
4. Save the service under a memorable name.
5. Go to **Keyboard Preferences → Shortcuts** (in System Preferences, or chooses “Configure Services” from the “Services” submenu in the Apple menu).
6. Select the “Services” category, locate your newly created service and assign it a shortcut (make sure it is checked to be active).

Voilà – you have a global keyboard shortcut to start your application. Rinse and repeat as needed. Note Automator services are pretty laggy when first started during a session, but reasonably responsive after that.