# Bind shortcut to applications

Tags: finder, keyboard, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I create a shortcut to open a specific application on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x)

I would like to bind a shortcut to `Google Chrome` and another shortcut to `Finder`... I configure as follows, but neither of them seems to work:

[image]
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard Shortcuts can't be used to create shortcuts to open applications. It's used to create shortcuts to existing menu items within applications.

I personally use [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/) for rapid access to applications, but you also use applications like [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) or [QuicKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/).

[Apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/) is another hot key manager that is specifically targeted towards activating, hiding and unhiding applications.