# Setting keyboard shortcut to switch to an application

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I create a shortcut to open a specific application on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x)

For example, I'd like to use <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to switch to my browser, with different numbers for the applications I switch between most regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend installing QuickSilver which is an excellent application launcher:

- http://qsapp.com/

In QuickSilver you can also setup keyboard shortcuts for various actions (called Triggers)  including launching an application.

If you click here

- http://qsapp.com/about.php

and then browse through the feature description until the eighth pane, you will learn about QuickSilver Triggers.

You could also have a quick look at the manual which is found here:

- http://mysite.verizon.net/hmelman/Quicksilver.pdf

Triggers are described starting on page 34.

Hope this helps.