# Can I get a Windows XP-like application taskbar in OS X?

Tags: macos, windows

Apologies for cross-posting in SE, but maybe I'll get a better response on an Apple/OS X specific forum!

I'm looking for a **Windows XP**-like taskbar application switcher in OS X. I'm **not** looking for anything icon-based like HyperDock and others, or anything that involves gestures like Expose. I want a simple bar at the bottom of the screen that I can click on buttons (**not** icons) to switch applications.

Also - answers like "just run Windows" are not appreciated ;)

Comment: What's wrong with the Dock?

Comment: I'm just used to a taskbar-like environment, both on Windows and Linux. Even on Windows 7 I converted the standard icon-like Dock-clone to the classic button-based taskbar.

Plus, on a multi-monitor setup, the dock just doesn't work as well and I personally find using Alt+Tab/Expose a total pain. Give me a taskbar and a launcher like GNOME-Do, Spotlight, Alfred or even Windows' Start Menu search over a dock any day of the week!

Comment: I have disabled the Dock and command+tab, and I've never used Exposé. I mostly rely on [keyboard shortcuts for applications](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x/20116#20116), Alfred, hiding applications, and ⌘`. There doesn't necessarily need to be any visual way to change windows or applications in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There was [Fantastik](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28378/fantasktik), but it's no longer in development.

Answer (score 1):

Try [uBar](http://ubarapp.com) (I am the developer). It's got the functionality you want, and does even more than the Windows taskbar ever did. For example, hold the Ctrl key to make it display CPU % and RAM usage for tasks...!

Comment: This looks interesting but three questions. 1. Does it force grouping of windows? I hate that. 2. Can I have it to the left of the monitor. 3. Can I  rearrange the windowbar items? Very important! I am looking for windows xp style task bar. The world has gone insane. I can not keep track of shit on MacOS.

Comment: I just tried it but it needs a bit more work. Custom size of the bar. Also, the ability to rearrange items is very important. Currently it is a bit random, perhaps the way they appear by asking the OS. Then, also, while I was able to disable grouping by app, they are grouped after each other, which is nice but at times, perhpas one would like them to be fully organised. One more thing. Disable click to minimize. It will just lead to me clicking it inadvertently ... also an option to hide away icons that are hidden or minimized .. but it is nice perhaps a little more touching up would be nice.

Comment: It is also not handling multiple desktops very well.

Comment: Numbers are showing even when there is just one window

Comment: Also, windows like uBar preferences should ideally also be displayed even for programs that are running in background ... i don't like the idea of hidden stuff underneath something that I can not get hold of.

Comment: Also clicking a grouped application, will show the popup, clicking on the one next to it will just hide the old one .. not activate the new one .. making it requiring two clicks. Does not make it intuitive. Even two clicks won't be enough if they don't occur with a certain delay. Making three or more clicks sometimes neccessary.

Comment: Desktop specific applicatoins would be nice. Meaning on a desktop I don't want anything to switch to another desktop ... to go there. and it should not contain anything from another desktoip ... allowing clean workplaces.