# how to get Finder to automatically open a Finder window / or always keep one open?

Tags: finder, window-manager, application-switcher

Let's say I have all my Finder windows closed. I'm in an application, like let's say Google Chrome. I <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to the Finder icon to switch to Finder. But it shows me nothing... no windows, because I have no windows open. I have to then invoke <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to open a Finder window.

Is there a way to get OSX to automatically open a Finder window when I <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to the Finder icon to switch to Finder, since anytime I switch to Finder, I always want a window?

Comment: This bugs me to no end when I want to drag a file to somewhere other than the desktop. You used to be able to drag a file to the finder icon and up would pop the top-most window or a window would be summoned, but this no longer works on Mountain Lion.

Comment: I have not tried it but this looks interesting. http://manytricks.com/witch/

Comment: @Buscar웃 Witch does not change how Finder reacts - just cmd-tab to separate Windows (I just tested this as I run Witch)

Comment: This is by desugn - any Document based app (ie with multiple windows) behaves the same way if no windows open

Comment: You can already open a new window if one is not already open by pressing the `Option` key during `Command - Tab` and releasing on it. As far as doing it automatically you'd probably have to script something.

Comment: Is there a way to do this via Applescript?

Answer (score 2):

> You can already open a new window if one is not already open by pressing the

COMMAND-TAB and hold down COMMAND.

Release TAB, keep holding down COMMAND,

then press OPTION and hold it down.

While still holding down OPTION, release COMMAND. Then release OPTION.

As far as doing it automatically you'd probably have to script something.

Source: @l'L'l

Comment: NOPE, it does not work !

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: COMMAND-TAB and hold down COMMAND. Release TAB, keep holding down COMMAND, then press OPTION and hold it down. While still holding down OPTION, release COMMAND. Then release OPTION. It's like playing a sonata. :-)

Comment: Sonata in C-mol ....it worked :)

Comment: Is there a way to make it default behavior?

Comment: Crazy! Why does this work? Anyone know what this is doing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction (in AppleScript terms) between reopening and activating an application.

- For example clicking a Dock icon reopens an application: if there are no visible windows, it opens a new default window, or if all windows are minimized, it unminimizes one of them.
- The application switcher activates applications by default, but if you hold option before releasing command, it reopens the selected application.
- Opening an application from the Spotlight menu, Finder, or Alfred reopens it.

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) has an option to tell applications with no windows to reopen:

[image]

Or if for example you use Alfred to [assign shortcuts to opening applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x/20116#20116), the shortcuts always reopen applications.