# Is there a way to hide certain apps from the cmd+tab menu?

Tags: macos, applications

Is there a way to hide certain apps from <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>?

The problem I'm facing is that I have some apps (like iTunes and of course Finder) always open. But when I'm working and switching between apps that are relevant for me (Chrome, Sublime, Terminal) with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> I'll always see these 'irrelevant' apps in the menu.

Thanks

Comment: Most of the answers here are irrelevant on Catalina, Big Sur, and later. Due to SIP any edits to `Info.plist` will cause the application to give an error on launch.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, however the only way I know of doing it also hides the dock icon.

Set the boolean LSUIElement.

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Source: [LSUIElement - Property List Key - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsuielement)

In macOS Catalina 10.15 and later, the boolean is enforced. Previously, a string of "1" could be used.

Source: [Re: LSUIElement and LSBackgroundOnly - Cocoa-dev mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2005/Jul/msg01146.html)

> you must modify the file named 'Info.plist' inside the Application's package (i.e. Sherlock.app/Contents/Info.plist). Open this file in your favorite text editor and add the following section (if it's already present simply change the 0 to a 1 in the string tag):

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

Source: [Hide any program’s Dock icon - Macworld Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20010701191518268)

Comment: holy smokes that worked better than expected thanks a lot!

Comment: Two comments.  First, the above [STRING] format will not work in 10.8 -- you need to use a boolean type.  Second, besides hiding the app from the application switcher, modifying the NSUIElement will also hide the menu bar, so using the "hidden" applications becomes quite difficult.

Comment: Have you had any luck with LSUIElement in Mavericks?

Comment: It told be I had to change permissions of the Info.plist file. I changed both the plist and the Contents folder, but still no luck. I use it with an app called TotalTerminal, and that warns me that it isn't quite version compatible when it launches. I bet that may be the inconsistency.

Comment: @atreat Ah, haven't tried it with TotalTerminal, although FYI they did release an update yesterday to provide Mavericks support

Comment: Yep, I downloaded the update, they now support it natively with their v1.4.2 release. https://github.com/binaryage/totalterminal/issues/3#issuecomment-26988325

Comment: In Mavericks, this crashes for me.  I've tried a couple of different applications.

Comment: @sandover This is probably because you're modifying a sandboxed app, which will cause it to crash upon launch to prevent modification.

Comment: Does this work in Yosemite? Using the app Fluid, I have tried making these changes but they seem to get overwritten as soon as I launch the program. The value for `LSUIElement` is `<false/>`. I tried simply changing that to `<true/>`, and also to `<string>1</string>`, but no dice. I save the plist file, then launch the program, but it appears in the command+tab switcher and on the dock. When I look at the plist file again, I see that it has reverted back to the original `<false/>` value.

Comment: will this also hide the application window but not terminate the application program (ie run in the background?)

Comment: This works great and it seems you can keep the application in the dock if you select the "Keep in Dock" option before doing this step.

Comment: @Gigi What is the ‘newest version’ of macOS specifically?

Comment: Adding this on Google Chrome will lead to app crashing. If I set the value to 0 or false it will not crash. Is there any reason why it would not work on some apps?

Comment: On Catalina, with either `LSUIElement` solution, I get  `The application <theAppYouModified> can’t be opened.`

Comment: Has anyone found a workaround for this with SIP?

Comment: This works great in Ventura 13.2.1, however the issue I'm encountering is that there's no way to `cmd+h` and hide the application anymore. I have a shortcut (via BTT) to bring it to the front/show it, but the toggle to hide it is no longer functional.

Answer (score 9):

You can set LSUIElement to 1 as string in the Info.plist:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

It removes applications from the application switcher, Dock, and the force quit window. It also removes the menu bar, so it's not really usable with Finder or iTunes.

Editing an Info.plist makes some applications like TextEdit and Chess crash on launch in 10.8. It also invalidates the code signatures of signed applications, so they are not allowed to access keychains automatically.

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/141753-lsuielement-and-lsbackgroundonly.html:

> NSUIElement is depreciated.  However, I remember clearly from working
>   at Apple (Apple DTS) a few years back that NSUIElement and LSUIElement
>   map to the same thing (at least it did back when I was there and I
>   doubt that would have changed).  Though NSUIElement is depreciated (NS
>   stands for next step of course! and LS stands for launch services),
>   they are exactly the same thing for all intents and purposes.

Both LSUIElement and NSUIElement still work, and both can also be set to true or 1 as integer.

```
grep -A1 [LN]SUIElement /Applications/*/Contents/Info.plist
```

[Information Property List Key Reference: Launch Services Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW1):

> `LSUIElement` (`String` - OS X) specifies whether the app runs as an agent app. If this key is set to “1”, Launch Services runs the app as an agent app. Agent apps do not appear in the Dock or in the Force Quit window. Although they typically run as background apps, they can come to the foreground to present a user interface if desired. A click on a window belonging to an agent app brings that app forward to handle events.
>
> The Dock and loginwindow are two apps that run as agent apps.

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) has an option to ignore applications:

[image]

I have just disabled the application switcher and Dock though. I mainly use [keyboard shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x/20116#20116) and Alfred to switch applications.

Comment: Setting `LSUIElement` in Slack's info.plist caused it to crash on launch for me.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I developed [GhostTile](http://ghosttile.kernelpanic.im)

Short Anwser: just try [GhostTile](http://ghosttile.kernelpanic.im). It's paid though but you can try as long as you can (steal the idea from Sublime Text)

Long Anwser:

AFAIK, There are two ways to achieve this:
1. Setup an App as Agent. E.g. Add `LSUIElement` key to App's Info.plist or Set App's activation policy to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory`.
2. Hook Dock or other related system process to ignore some apps. Thanks to SIP(Rootless) on El Captian. It's not recommended to do so.

GhostTile is focus on hiding Apps from Dock. It's easy to use and provide multiple ways to manage the apps you hide. There is no on-disk modification, so you won't break apps' codesign signature.

Other features:

- You can still get notified for the App's Dock Activity
- Expose-like Overview
- Alfred Workflow

Comment: Just tried this app and *none* of the apps I tried are "supported yet". Finder, Mail, iOS Simulator...

Comment: @pkamb I'm sorry but all the apps your tried is protected by System Integration Protection (SIP) introduced in El Capitan. Could you please try other third party apps? or turn SIP off?

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the answer. I'd suggest a more informative error message or link to an FAQ!

Comment: How do I hide Ghost Title from Cmd+Tab launcher ? I tried adding <key>NSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string> to Info.plist and restarting the app. It didnt work

Comment: @mac There is a preference option called "Hide GhostTile from Dock"

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know that option can hide ghosttile from Cmd+Tab laucher as well ;)

Comment: That option has a unintended consequence. It adds a item in top menu bar making it cluttered now ;)

Comment: Tested it, but on OSX Sierra it seems also "Not supported yet" for third party applications.

Comment: @hewigovens interesting application. how did you implement the dock hiding and window switcher hiding? which APIs did you use? looking to find a similar possibility for a project. thanks in advance!

Comment: Hugely disappointed.  GhostTile appears to be for hiding from the *dock* not the Application Switcher, which is what this question was about and is what I was looking for.  Just wasted a bunch of time trying to figure out why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be late to the party, but indeed as previous answers and comments state, this might make some applications to crash on launch. I can't make this work in Yosemite although I was able to make it work before on another Mac. Changing the TotalTerminal Info.plist did not do anything, and changing the `Applications/Utilities/Terminal/Info.plist` caused the crash.

As @atreat mentioned in one of the comments, the guys from **TotalTerminal** are [now supporting this hide](https://github.com/binaryage/totalterminal/issues/3#issuecomment-26988325) via a simple command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal TotalTerminalHideDockIcon -bool YES
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an iPhone and has similar problem with [hiding an app from the App Switcher](http://ihacksblog.com/blacklistswitcher9-hide-iphone-apps-from-app-switcher/), you can install something like BlacklistSwitcher9.