# Is there any way to remove an app icon (especially stickies) on mac's application switcher (cmd+tab menu)?

Tags: mac, macos, macbook-pro, application-switcher

On Mac's application switcher I want to hide some applications such as Stickies. I always use Stickies, it is really useful for me that's why it's always running. But, I'm really fed up with it on <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇥ TAB</kbd>. I want to get rid of it

Is there a way to do within altering any settings in macbook or using any third party software?

I tried the solution at "[Is there a way to hide certain apps from the cmd+tab menu?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92004/is-there-a-way-to-hide-certain-apps-from-the-cmdtab-menu)". But it doesnot work maybe because of OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this app. (It's paid though) [GhostTile](http://ghosttile.kernelpanic.im/)