# Disable the sleep function of the MacBook touch bar

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, touch-bar

I got the new MacBook Pro and I found out that the touch bar goes to sleep after 75 seconds of inactivity. This function is quite annoying to me.

Is it possible to disable the sleep function of the touch bar for the 75 seconds of inactivity? I have googled it, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Did you try the preference pane? I think it is in System Preferences > Energy Save. You could also search the System Prefs. pane in the top right corner, try searching there for something like "Touch Bar"

Comment: Yeah, but there isn't a property to disable the sleep function and the search does not show viable results.

Comment: I want this too, but is there any risk of burn-in on the display if it's always on? I saw an apple watch that was pretty badly burnt in in an Apple store. So if it's the same type of display, then it might be bad to keep it always on.

Comment: I think it could be possible, but otherwise, if you are working the whole day with the Macbook the Touch Bar does not go to sleep. I think the risk for a burn-in is very low, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use my script until Apple adds a preference for the Touch Bar.

It simulates keyboard activity by sending the command for the fn-key every 60 seconds. You should not notice it while typing. Keep in mind, however, that this will prevent display sleep / system sleep as well.

Copy and paste the following code into the "Script Editor" application on your MacBook Pro with Touch Bar:

```
(*
1. Save as an Application: Script Editor > File > Export… > File Format: Application
2. Check "Stay open after run handler"
3. Run the app or add it to your login items: System Preferences > Users & Groups > User > Login Items > Press the "+" button

# http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269174/disable-the-sleep-function-of-the-macbook-touch-bar
*)

on idle
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke (key code 63) -- press fn key
    delay 60
end idle
```

Please let us know if this solves your issue.

Comment: I found out that 60 seconds interval is too long, 30 seconds works for me

Comment: This seems not to be working for me.  I realize that it was posted 5 years ago and I assume Apple has changed things so much that it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Through a lot of personal experimentation, I've discovered the Touch Bar expects physical keyboard strokes in order to prevent it from going to sleep (i.e. not via virtualized keyboard strokes). There's another later answer in this thread that also confirms this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393260/432503

Answer (score 9):

I arrived here after I started searching for a similar solution.

Unfortunately, it seems that the touchbar "accepts" only physical keystroke/ movements.

I tried the @oa-'s script but it doesn't work on 10.15.5.

Also tried caffeine/ Jiggler/  disabling idle in terminal... still the touchpad isn't stopping from going to sleep.

My problem is that my touchpad is broken (from 0 to the right-end it starts flickering on full brightness if it goes to sleep).

What I'm thinking now but with potentially more system wide impact is resetting the HIDIdleTime (I'm not sure yet if the touchpad query the time from there).

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution (because I now have the same problem)?

Comment: Have the same problem, can I sue Apple if I get blind of the crazy blinks..

Comment: I believe if your mac new enough, AND if your keyboard have problems (which lots of keyboards have, when it duplicates keystrokes, or some of them not being pressed instead), you can qualify for keyboard replacement program, which also replaces touchbar. I missed that opportunity this spring since I limited only to mac now (and it takes a month at regular times from what I heard)

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to oa-'s script (looks great, but I'd rather not forego the display sleep functionality), I searched far and wide for any other solution. I found no complete one, but here's a partial one that might alleviate the worst part of the pain. I find that the single most annoying thing about the disappearing Touch Bar is its effect on the esc key. I use that all the time! Now you have to tap the bar twice: once to wake it up, and then again to press esc. (Or alternatively, press the fn key to wake up the bar, then press esc.)

Here is a way to at least rescue esc functionality by adding it to what remains of the physical keyboard. You can remap the caps lock key to be your esc key. You'll lose caps lock functionality, which is also a drawback, but maybe not as bad as losing esc. (Alternatively, you can remap the control, option, or command key instead.) Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys, and use the drop downs to choose the action you want.

https://www.imore.com/how-use-esc-key-touch-bar-macbook-pro

Comment: (Personally, I haven't decided yet whether this is worth it. Retraining myself to hit caps lock instead of esc might be more trouble than it's worth. But will try it out...)

Comment: You can also use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to remap a key to Esc in advanced, customizable ways. For example, you can make it so that pressing Ctrl sends Esc but holding Ctrl acts as normal, or you can make it so that Caps Lock acts as Esc in Emacs and MacVim but acts normal in other applications.

Answer (score 1):

I found @oa-'s answer useful. I used their script as posted in the answer.

```
(*
1. Save as an Application: Script Editor > File > Export… > File Format: Application
2. Check "Stay open after run handler"
3. Run the app or add it to your login items: System Preferences > Users & Groups > User > Login Items > Press the "+" button

# http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269174/disable-the-sleep-function-of-the-macbook-touch-bar
*)

on idle
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke (key code 63) -- press fn key
    delay 60
end idle
```

However it adds the applescript application to switcher which is an annoyance to me. To remove the script from the `Cmd+Tab` switcher, find the applescript application and edit its `Info.plist` file (right click the app file -> `Show Package Contents`, open `Info.plist` with text editor). You should add

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

to it so it becomes hidden from app switcher. If you want to trace & kill the app later, use the terminal to hunt it down: `ps aux | grep YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME` and `kill PROCESS_ID`.

Used for assistance: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/92017/123820

Comment: As another suggestion, try out open source project "My Touchbar My Rules" offering full customization of touchbar. https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR/

Comment: this is great but I couldn't find an option for AlwaysOn

Answer (score 0):

Try this guys its works for me

https://medium.com/macoclock/macbook-touchbar-flicker-fix-bafa754aae13

The script there is:

```
global computerIsInUse, resetTime
  
on run
    set computerIsInUse to true
    set resetTime to (do shell script "date +%s") as integer
end run

on idle
    set idleTime to (do shell script "ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | awk '/HIDIdleTime/ {print $NF; exit}'") as integer
    if idleTime is greater than 7.4E+10 then
        if computerIsInUse then
            do shell script "pkill TouchBarServer" user name "YourUserNameGoesThere" password "YourPasswordGoesThere" with administrator privileges
            set computerIsInUse to false
        end if
    end if
    if idleTime is less than 7.4E+10 then
        set computerIsInUse to true
    end if
    
    set now to (do shell script "date +%s") as integer
    if (not computerIsInUse) and ((now - resetTime) is greater than 59) then
        do shell script "pkill TouchBarServer" user name "YourUserNameGoesThere" password "YourPasswordGoesThere" with administrator privileges
        set resetTime to (do shell script "date +%s") as integer
    end if
    return 1
end idle
```

> Bear in mind to change twice `YourUserNameGoesThere` and twice
> `YourPasswordGoesThere`.
>
> A little explanation, what this script does:
>
> 1. On line 9 it checks for how long your are not using your computer:
>    idleTime
> 2. Because your TouchBar goes completely off after ~75 seconds,
>    it checks if that idleTime is before or after 74 seconds: 7.4E+10.
> 3. In
>    case the idleTime goes through those 75 seconds, it restarts TouchBar
>    and set computerIsInUse to false, because you are obviously not using
>    the computer (not pressing keys or mouse, etc.).
> 4. And if
>    computerIsInUse is false (which happens only after those 75 seconds)
>    it restarts TouchBar immediately and then every 60 seconds (more than
>    59 seconds). Why? Because if not, your Touchbar will fade away after
>    another 60 seconds. This script has to restart it every 60 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.