# How do I hide a 3rd party App completely?

Tags: terminal

Is there a terminal command or solution to allow me to visually remove the app icon from the Dock and from the shortcut viewer ( tab + option )?

Ideally, the app should be 100% invisible and running in the background.

i tried ghostviewer and it didnt work. thanks

Comment: What is it you want to do and why?

Comment: A specific app, or just any app? | Do you mean Command + Tab for the applications switcher function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to hide certain apps from the cmd+tab menu?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92004/is-there-a-way-to-hide-certain-apps-from-the-cmdtab-menu)