# How to create a keyboard short cut (F7) for example to launch the terminal app?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu

How to create a custom keyboard shortcut that launches a terminal window?

e.g. when I press F7, it would launch a new terminal window no matter what application is in the foreground.

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Another related question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010