# How can I change OS X Double-Click on Title Bar to be like Windows?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, software-recommendation

I love my Mac eternally but there is one thing I miss from my former Windows days. When I want to toggle between maximize and restore window, on Windows I would double-click the title bar, and that would invoke the toggle.

However with older versions of OS X, a double click on the title bar causes the window to minimize, forcing me to hit F10, then locate the minimized window, then click on it. Too many steps.

Is there any way to make OS X perform the toggle on double-click?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

1. Choose Apple Menu → System Preferences, then click Dock.
2. Select check box **Double-click a window’s title bar to zoom**.

   [image]
3. **Double click** on window's title bar to maximise the window.

Zoom expands a window to fill the space between the Dock and the menu bar. If the Dock is along the side of the screen, the window fills the space below the menu bar and to the side of the Dock.

---

Up to macOS High Sierra 10.14:
Perform steps 1 and 2, then **Shift + Double click** on title bar to maximise the window.

Comment: Sorry, it's already set to 'zoom' for me and enabled, but if I do the same for Finder (and some other windows), it just becomes 'slightly' bigger and double clicking again comes back to a smaller size - I don't know what exactly it is 'zooming' to when there's so much more space! Macs are funny.

Comment: This stopped working for me with the upgrade to Big Sur (OS 11.x).  Mine was set to Zoom but wasn't working. I had to toggle to Minimize and back to Zoom to get it to work.

Comment: To the action I expect, I had to set it to Minimize, double click to minimize the window I wanted to maximize and then set it to Zoom again and it started working as I expect...

Answer (score 15):

`Shift + Dbl-Click` works perfectly!

Comment: When I press shift and double click on the title bar, it does a slow animation that minimizes the application to the bottom right. On Windows a double click on the title bar maximizes the window

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with third-party software

### [BetterSnapTool](http://blog.boastr.net/bettersnaptool/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) ($1.99)

[image: Imgur]

Comment: To anybody coming across this post years later, it is now €3.49 (roughly USD $4.19). :)

Comment: I have purchased BetterSnapTool and am well pleased.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find anything that makes double click to maximize available, but I found using http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/ a good alternative. (It also gives you active windows preview in your dock on top of window management.)

> HyperDock brings advanced window management features to Mac OS:
>
> Move & resize windows just by holding down keys and/or moving your mouse.
> Automatically resize windows when dragging to screen edges (Window Snapping).

By default you can snap window to sides/maximize with ctrl + cmd + arrow keys.

---

I also found a better alternative (even more convenient than the Windows feature you were asking about): Better Touch Tool from http://www.boastr.de/ (free)

Add your custom gesture like this (actually you can choose among tons of predefined actions and bind them to key combinations/ trackpad gestures):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to Apple icon > System Preferences > Dock > Select "Double-click a window's title bar to" "Zoom", then it should work. As of now yours is minimize.

Comment: I wish it would maximize to the full screen dimensions, but this is certainly better than nothing!

Comment: Just realized, combining this answer with shift double click as per Anton Orel, does the job magnificently!

Comment: I don't know if this was for an older version of macOS or what, but this no longer works consistently. I still have programs that, when I shift-double-click the title bar, it just goes to a previously-set size that it remembered.

Comment: Or just select "Window" -> "Zoom" from the menu bar (since not all apps have a title bar to click on)

Answer (score 3):

If you move the cursor to a corner of the window (until ↔ appears) and double click, it will expand in that direction. Not a 100% solution, but still good.

Comment: Similarly, if you move the cursor to a corner of the window, until the diagonal arrow cursor appears, you can hold down Option and double-click and the window will maximize in both the horizontal and vertical directions.

Answer (score 2):

[Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) and [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) allow setting up keyboard shortcuts for maximizing and restoring windows:

[image]
[image]

I never minimize windows, and I don't use any window management applications either. I think it's easier to just use ⌘H and to [focus applications with keyboard shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010).

Comment: this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

On Big Sur, I had to re-enable the System Preferences > Dock > Select "Double-click a window's title bar to" "Zoom" option.

I.e. Uncheck > Check

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2022**

For **macos mojave** and later -

One can click on the arrow that pops up on the corner of the window and then use option-double click to maximise it.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) to be a great free tool for a lot of things "window resizing" - works like magic!

[image: The way Spectacle options look on my screen]

Comment: Just noting that Spectacle is no longer being maintained. See https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle#important-note