# Hotkey for new Finder window

Tags: macos, keyboard

On my old MacBook, I could hit <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and get a new Finder window with the sidebar (Downloads, Documents, etc…).

On my new Mac, that same command only gives me a Spotlight window which excludes the sidebar.

Is there a way to get the hotkey shortcut going again so that I don't have to <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> to the Finder each time to hit <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>?

<sup>I am on a Mac i5 MacBook Pro.</sup>

Comment: If you want to assign a keyboard shortcut for focusing Finder (and opening a new window if there are no open windows), see [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x/20116#20116) for different ways to assign keyboard shortcuts for opening applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to show the sidebar (or select **View > Show Sidebar** from the Finder menubar).