# Switching to #x application in the dock

Tags: macos, keyboard, dock

I would like to hit cmd+X to switch to (or launch, if it's not running) the #X application in the Dock, without hardconding that application.

I.e. if my third application in the dock is the Terminal, I hit cmd+3 and I switch to the terminal, but if I then move Adium to that position, cmd+3 automatically opens Adium.

Can this be done on OSX 10.8 (or 10.9)?

Even better, though that's not required, if in case I hit the combination of the already active application, it hides it instead.

Comment: _(if someone has a better title for this, please edit, thanks)_

Answer (score 3):

You could save one AppleScript for clicking each Dock icon:

`for i in {1..9};do echo 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock" to click UI element '$i' of list 1'>~/Library/Scripts/Focus\ Application\ $i.applescript;done`

Then use [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to assign shortcuts to the scripts.

I find it easier to just [assign keyboard shortcuts for applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x/20116#20116) though.

Comment: I'll leave it open for a while, just in case someone comes up with an application which does that.

Answer (score 1):

With AppleScript you can do something like that :

```
tell application "System Events"
    click item # of UI elements of list 1 of process "Dock"
end tell
```

But the actual problem is binding it to the shortcuts.

Edit:As Lauri Ranta reminded me by his anwers, there is FastScripts.