# How to create a hotkey that opens Emacs in MacOS?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, preferences, shortcuts-app, emacs

I have just bought a MacBook Air for professional reasons and I am new to MacOS. Before that, I have been using Linux (Ubuntu and NixOS) for a long time.

I would like to define a hotkey to open my beloved editor Emacs. I tried:

[image]

Unfortunately, it does **not** work.

How can I fix this? Why it does not work?

Also, considering my lack of common-sense, what would be a good keybinding?

Obs.: I used to use `super-key` (windows logo) and letter `e`.

Thanks.

Comment: This has come up before. Check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431395/9058 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/439185/9058 for how to use the Shortcuts application for this.

Comment: Also, to answer the "Why it does not work" part: The preferences you used allow to rebind keyboard shortcuts *within* applications, you can't define new global keyboard shortcuts there. Basically you told the system to bind the menu entry "Emacs" of the application "Emacs" to shift-cmd-E.

Comment: Having said that: I usually have Emacs and all the other applications I regularly use auto-start at login, and then just never quit them :-)