# closing all notification alerts at once

Tags: macos, notifications, alert

The difference between alerts and banners is that alerts require user input to disappear, whereas banners go away on their own. **Is there a way to close all notification alerts at once?**

In the example below, there are 6 alerts from one application. I'd like to be able to OPTION-click "Close" or hit a keyboard shortcut to dismiss all of them. Ideally, I'd be able to dismiss all alerts on a per application basis. But I'd settle for the ability to dismiss alerts universally.

[image: Omnifocus alerts]

Comment: Close but not quite, since this question asks for a way to close _all_ notifications. @philpirozhkov

Comment: Although that question has an answer, whereas mine doesn't, so yeah, the best solution for me is probably to implement the answer listed at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155670/keyboard-shortcut-to-dismiss-notifications

Answer (score 0):

Concerning closing **all** alert notification via a keyboard shortcut, you have the options listed below available. Both use a bit of AppleScript to close the alert notifications by automatically pressing "Close" on each notification until there are no more notification available. The script has been extensively tested and should cover all edge cases with proper error handling.

### Using an Alfred workflow

If you use Alfred, you have this workflow available: [Notification dismisser](https://github.com/zakyum/alfred-notification-dismisser). It will close all the currently displayed notifications with a shortcut or Alfred keyword. Super simple to use and works as expected.

### Without using Alfred

If you don't use Alfred, you can take the [main script](https://github.com/zakyum/alfred-notification-dismisser/blob/master/src/dismiss-active-notifications.applescript) from the workflow and using Automator save it as a "Quick Action". Then set a keyboard shortcut for it in System Preferences. Does the same as the workflow, albeit requires a bit more effort than clicking "install" as with Alfred.

<sub>*Full disclosure, I'm the author of the workflow and script. Hope it helps someone to save a couple precious seconds!*</sub>