# Dismiss Calendar notification popups more easily

Tags: macos, notifications, calendar, big-sur

After upgrading to Big Sur, calendar notifications on Mac OS have become harder to dismiss.  The notification appears in the upper-right of the screen, and to dismiss it, one must hover over the upper-left of the notification to cause an 'x' to appear, and then click on the 'x'.  Subjectively, I find it tedious to dismiss the notification: the zone where I have to click seems small and requires fairly precise work with my mouse.

Is there a faster way to dismiss the notification?  Perhaps a keyboard shortcut or some other trick?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good question - I am bothered by the same issue.  I Googled, and found this exact topic, posted here about 6 years ago.

[Can macOS have a keyboard shortcut to dismiss notifications?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155670/can-macos-have-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-dismiss-notifications)

There's a pretty good discussion about this, and I downloaded the "Alfred" workflow solution since I own the app.  The alfred-notification-dismisser by zakyum on GitHub is located [here](https://github.com/zakyum/alfred-notification-dismisser).

Answer (score -1):

You can drag notifications off to the right to dismiss them.

Comment: Not sure where the downvotes are suddenly coming from. Dragging to dismiss does still work, as of macOS 12.0.1.

Comment: "Dragging off" (or similarly two-finger swiping off") only puts a notification in the action center and it will come back whenever it gets a chance (e.g., next screen unlock).