# Ctrl + Alt + Delete: Mac Equivalent?

Tags: macos, keyboard

**Ctrl + Alt + Delete** on Windows provides a variety of functions, the main one of interest being the Task Manager. Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut & indeed Task Manager for carrying out such tasks as quitting an application that maybe "hanging" (amongst other things) for Apple Macs, or indeed anything similar ?

Comment: Please describe what specific functionalities you are looking for.

Comment: @Simon Of interest: Bill Gates admits Control-Alt-Delete was a mistake, blames IBM http://www.theverge.com/2013/9/26/4772680/bill-gates-admits-ctrl-alt-del-was-a-mistake

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut you’re looking for is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⎋</kbd>, alternatively known as <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>escape</kbd>. This will bring up the *Force Quit Applications* window (see screenshot below).

[image: Force Quit Window]

Comment: Is Activity Monitor equivalent or similar to the Windows Task Manager ?

Comment: @Simon If you want to see in more detail what's going on instead of just force-quitting an app, yes.  The force-quit shortcut is much easier to use if you just want to quickly kill a misbehaving application.

Comment: I had no idea that ⎋ was Escape -- thanks for clearing this up for me!

Comment: @MathiasBynens what about now? this doesn't seem to be the case in mac Mojave.

Answer (score 34):

There is no all in one equivalent:

- The equivalent of the Windows Task Manager is The Activity Monitor app.
- The equivalent of Close Session or Shut Down are found in the Apple Menu.
- The equivalent of Change Password is the Users pane of the Configuration app.
- The equivalent of Lock Computer is "Login Window..." under the User (your user name) menu.

Comment: The equivalent of Lock Computer is...?

Comment: @Simon - I don't know: I don't need it. But if somebody has the answer, feel free to edit my answer or add it as comment.

Comment: OK Excellent...

Comment: For "Lock Computer" see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac

Comment: @patrix Cheers !

Comment: @Simon Added Lock Computer equivalent. You can also set the screen saver to require a password and just activate the screen saver when you leave your desk (I use a hot corner to do this).

Comment: @chaiguy V.Good

Comment: If you just need to lock your computer quickly, you can press either Control+Shift+Eject or in keyboards without an Eject key you can use Control+Shift+Power

Answer (score 6):

To complete previous answers :

- The shortcut control-eject brings up the shutdown/reboot confirmation dialog (I use this a lot : you just have to type control-eject then enter to shutdown. Very handy!)
- Pressing cmd-shift-Q brings up the quit session confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> to force applications to quit.

For Task Manager style stuff Activity Monitor is it by default and its not key invoked.

You could attach a key combo in preferences to Activity Monitor
Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts -->

**Application**: Finder
**Menu Title**: whatever
**Keyboard Shortcut**: You key combo.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>If you just need to lock your computer quickly, you can press:</strike>

<kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>

**Edit:** Unfortunately, one of Apple's OS updates killed the above key combination for no good reason. So the only key combination available now is this less convenient one (if you have a Mac Mini or an iMac you have to press the physical Power button on the computer in addition to the other two keys in the keyboard):

<kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Power ⌽</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Activity Monitor` and create a global keyboard shortcut to it via [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I normally open terminal. Then use top and kill the process.

Comment: Two problems with this answer: 1 you're starting a new process which will suck on a bogged down machine. 2 anybody unfamiliar with terminal will need a little more info.

Answer (score 1):

see http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22781?viewlocale=en_US
That is the answer to Ctrl + Alt + Delete on a PC.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score -2):

Ctrl + Shift + ESC gives you the task manager. This solved my problem. Credit to: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3718443?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: How does this add to or improve on http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/86015/237 or other answers here?

Answer (score -3):

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt(Alt)</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Answer (score -4):

Ctrl + Alt + Delete in Windows is equivalent to 
Command + fn + delete in Mac OS X