# How to migrate aliases from bash to zsh

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, zsh

I want to start using `zsh` as recommended by Apple for Mac OS Catalina. How do I migrate my aliases that I have defined in the `~/.bash_profile` to the new shell?

Comment: AFIK, the syntax for the alias definition works the same in bash and zsh, so unless you have  some specific bashism in your aliases, you can simply copy and paste them. One point to be aware of, is that bash by default does  not expand aliases in interactive shells, zsh does, and if you want to mimic this, you have to request this bash-like behaviour in zsh. However, if you place your aliases into .zshrc, the difference does not matter, since this file is processed by interactive shells only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If until now you've been using `~/.bash_profile` for the loading the aliases, here are some of the ways you can migrate your aliases:

---

### 1. Copy the contents:

The most assiduous and obvious way is to copy the contents of your `~/.bash_profile`  to `~/.zshrc`. It works particularly when you are moving on from `bash` to `zsh` for good.

---

### 2. Pull out aliases and then source them:

Another <sup>*</sup>way is:

1. Create a new file that will contain the aliases (let's call it `~/.aliases`);
2. Copy the contents of `~/.bash_profile` to the new aliases file;
3. Modify the `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.zshrc` to source the new file.

Put the following in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.aliases ]; then
   . ~/.aliases
fi
```

and put the following in `~/.zshrc`:

```
source $HOME/.aliases
```

This way the aliases will be available for both shells. More importantly, if you make changes to the aliases, the changes will cascade to both shells automatically.

---

*<sup><sup>*</sup> Taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/195357)</sup>*

Comment: This answer was the solution for me. Thanks @displayName

Answer (score 1):

I usually copy the whole file and in case delete the lines that I don't need. This always worked well for me:

```
cat .bash_profile >> .zshrc
```